# Customize Friend Invite Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is pretty straightforward, is there any way to customize the Facebook friend multi-select dialog for App Invitations ? We are talking about frontend design, not additional functionalities.

My intuitive understanding dictates it is hard to alter the existing code in the JS SDK, maybe I need a side project that is extensible enough to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer = yes

The dialog its self is not something you can change but you can form your multi friend selection in anyway you like.

here is Facebook's example
[Custom Multi Friend Selector Example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/)